# Angularjs Read more or less text button partially working

Tags: angularjs

The code below was used to display three database content post/rows using angularjs. Each displayed rows/data has ReadMore or ReadLess button attached to it.

The Issue am having now is that when I click on readmore button of the first post, it expands all the other database rows/post(ie Second and Third rows/post were also expanded).

I have taught of adding something like `{{post.id}}` to ensure that only the click Readmore post gets affected but do not know where it can be implemented. can someone help me with that.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!--read more text starts here-->

  <!--read more text ends-->

</head>

<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl'>
    <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>

      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      {{ post.id }}<br> 
      {{ post.content | limitTo:numLimit }}
      <div class="post-text">

        <button type='button' ng-click="readMore()">read more</button>
        <button type='button' ng-click="readLess()">read less</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
    fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        // read more or less text starts here
        $scope.numLimit = 200;
        $scope.readMore = function() {
          $scope.numLimit = 10000;
        };

        $scope.readLess = function() {
          $scope.numLimit = 200;
        };

        // // read more or less text ends here

        // Fetch post data
        $scope.getPosts = function() {

          $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'likeunlike.php',
            data: {
              request: 1
            }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.posts = response.data;
          });
        }
        $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data
      }
    ]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the PHP code or does this all need to happen in javascript?

Comment: @Tyler, Php code is okay. It needs javascript/angularjs implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add `numLimit` to each post rather than the scope. You can do this in the PHP when you are fetching the posts or you can do this in your controller in your success function. Since you are using the `$scope` for each post, anything you do to the `$scope.numLimit`, it will do it for all posts. Once you add `numLimit` to each post, in either the javascript or php, you can update your html and `readMore()` and `readLess()` functions.

In the html we will switch the `limitTo` to use the `post.numLimit` value and then pass the post in to your `readMore` and `readLess` functions.

**.html**

```
<!-- most code left out for brevity -->
<div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>

    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    {{ post.id }}<br> 
    {{ post.content | limitTo:post.numLimit }}
    <div class="post-text">

        <button type='button' ng-click="readMore(post)">read more</button>
        <button type='button' ng-click="readLess(post)">read less</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

In the javascript, we will switch the two functions to update the `numLimit` on the post, rather than the `scope`. We will also initialize each post with the lower `numLimit`.

**.js**

```
// read more or less text starts here
//$scope.numLimit = 200; - can remove this
$scope.readMore = function(post) {
    post.numLimit = 10000;
};

$scope.readLess = function(post) {
    post.numLimit = 200;
};

// read more or less text ends here

// Fetch post data
$scope.getPosts = function() {

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'likeunlike.php',
        data: {
            request: 1
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.posts = response.data;

        // this will initialize all posts to the lower numLimit
        angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){
            post.numLimit = 200;
        })

    });
}

$scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data
```

Comment: :-) I posted the exact same solution at the exact same time.

Comment: @Tonio Definitely the correct way to solve this problem :)

Comment: @Tyler, Thanks for your effort. the default text limit should be 200 when page is first displayed. but  your solution overides the default value limit of (200)  when displayed. Thats, it shows all the text in the row when displayed first. The content should show text limit of 200 when displayed first as i have coded above. when click on ReadMore, it will then show all the content(10,000). when click on Readless, it will show back 200 text. between thanks so far. waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: @chinazaike Please try this updated version, I added a foreach to initialize each post. What was happening was you weren't initializing the posts with a `numLimit`, so when it was undefined it wasn't limiting the text at all. Once you clicked either button it was initializing that property to the button's respective value. This edit should allow each post to start with the less text.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I will buy you beer next time. God bless

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because `$scope.numLimit` is a field for the entire controller scope, not for the each individual post. To do this for each of the posts you need something like this:

```
//JS code
$scope.readMore = function(post) {
          post.numLimit = 10000;
        };

        $scope.readLess = function(post) {
          post.numLimit = 200;
        };

//HTML code
<button type='button' ng-click="readMore(post)">read more</button>
<button type='button' ng-click="readLess(post)">read less</button>
```

You will obviously need to initialise `numLimit` for each post somewhere (maybe in succesCallback), but that is basically it. Although I prefer to set initialisations for each element on the server side, here is one way to do it on the client:

```
// Fetch post data
$scope.getPosts = function() {

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'likeunlike.php',
        data: {
            request: 1
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.posts = response.data;

        $scope.posts.forEach(function(post){
            post.numLimit = 200;
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: @Eminala, Thanks for your effort. the default text limit should be 200 when page is first displayed. but  your solution overides the default value limit of (200)  when displayed. Thats, it shows all the text in the row when displayed first. The content should show text limit of 200 when displayed first as i have coded above. when click on ReadMore, it will then show all the content(10,000). when click on Readless, it will show back 200 text. between thanks so far. waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: I've added the initialisation as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Why are you having an issue:**

The number numLimit is unique to all of your posts, so when you click on "readMore()" for any of the posts, it update this variable that every post uses, that is why you are having the problem.

**How to fix it**
I suggest that you add a variable inside each post called numLimit, this way each post will have their own "numLimit".
When you will click on "readMore()", you will pass the post and change the number.

I modified your code below: 2 changes:

- getPosts iterates on the post to add numLimit to each post
- readMore/readLess now have the current post as parameter

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!--read more text starts here-->

  <!--read more text ends-->

</head>

<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl'>
    <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>

      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
      {{ post.id }}<br> 
      {{ post.content | limitTo:post.numLimit }}
      <div class="post-text">

        <button type='button' ng-click="readMore(post)">read more</button>
        <button type='button' ng-click="readLess(post)">read less</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
    fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        // read more or less text starts here
        $scope.readMore = function(post) {
          post.numLimit = 10000;
        };

        $scope.readLess = function(post) {
          post.numLimit = 200;
        };

        // // read more or less text ends here

        // Fetch post data
        $scope.getPosts = function() {

          $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'likeunlike.php',
            data: {
              request: 1
            }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.posts = response.data;
            
            for ( let post of posts ) {
               post.numLimit = 200;
            }
            
          });
        }
        $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data
      }
    ]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. the default text limit should be 200 when page is first displayed. but  your solution overides the default value limit of (200)  when displayed. Thats, it shows all the text in the row when displayed first. The content should show text limit of 200 when displayed first as i have coded above. when click on ReadMore, it will then show all the content(10,000). when click on Readless, it will show back 200 text. between thanks so far. waiting for your reply. Thanks